# How Can I Set Up DNS Server on Virtual Network w/out Internet?

Tags: dns, bind, libvirt, openldap, sssd

I'm trying to set up a virtual network populated with 4 CentOS 7 servers for testing purposes.  I have successfully configured a Kerberos server and a secondary Kerberos server.  However, when it comes to OpenLDAP, it seems that a DNS server is needed.

I decided to add an internet-facing interface on the system with the LDAP and DNS servers to allow the `named` server to *forward* unresolved dns requests to my router's DNS server. While my local `named` server correctly propagates the names of the other clients on the virtual network, it seems that it's not forwarding unknown requests.  Here's the pertinent lines from my `/etc/named.conf` file:

```
options {
// turns on IPv6 for port 53, IPv4 is on by default for all ifaces
listen-on-v6 {any;};
// As per RHEL7 IdM guide, disable empty zones for bind9.9
empty-zones-enable no;

...trunc...

forward first;
forwarders {
        192.168.1.1;
};
allow-recursion { any; };
dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation no;
```

Comment: Can you please tell us how you determined that OpenLDAP requires a DNS server?

Comment: @Celada I'm trying to backtrack my investigation of this issue; I believe it may, actually, be related to `SSSD`

Comment: Strange...I thought Kerberos needed a name server for rdns look ups to verify a host isn't spoofing.